# Collective Event Handler in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, event-handling

On my WPF Window, I want the textboxes to have a slightly blue background when the cursor is on them. I created two simple event handlers (GotFocus and LostFocus) to do this.

```
private void textBox1_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Background = (Brush)new BrushConverter().ConvertFrom("#FFE6E6FF");
        }

        private void textBox1_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Background = Brushes.White;
        }
```

Is there a way I can direct every textbox to one eventhandler that gives the background to the respective textbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simple.  Put the event hook on the outermost container of all of the text boxes:

```
<Window TextBox.GotFocus="textBox1_GotFocus" TextBox.LostFocus="textBox1_LostFocus">
   <TextBox ... >
   <TextBox ... >
   <TextBox ... >
</Window>
```

To make it operate on the correct textbox, cast the "sender" parameter as a textbox:

```
private void textBox1_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ((TextBox)sender).Background = (Brush)new BrushConverter().ConvertFrom("#FFE6E6FF");
}
```

Comment: The problem is that, in my code it sets the background of textbox1. How can I make it set the background of whichever textbox triggered the event?